# Excel says "Too many different cell formats" and has lots of duplicated built-in styles

Tags: microsoft-excel

A large spreadsheet I have been using for years has suddenly began to pop-up an error `Too many different cell formats` when I try to apply formats.

When I look at the Styles I do see an enormous number of Custom Styles that begin with the names of built-in styles like `20% Accent1`.  Picking one at random it looks exactly like that built-in style but its full name is `20% Accent1 2 2 3 2 2 2`.  I don't know where these came from and I don't want them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft explains this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/too-many-different-cell-formats-in-excel): Massive numbers of custom styles duplicating built-in styles can be caused by copying and pasting from other workbooks.  Excel 2007 and later versions accommodate 64,000 different styles per workbook, so by the time you encounter this message you have quite a mess, and the styles are probably consuming ~1.5MB of space in the file!

An expeditious fix is to run the following macro to delete all the custom styles:

```
Public Sub StyleCleanup()
    Dim st As Style
    For Each st In ActiveWorkbook.Styles
      If Not st.BuiltIn Then
        st.Delete
      End If
    Next
End Sub
```

To do this in the problematic workbook:

1. Press Alt-F11 to open the VBA editor.
2. Insert >> Module
3. Paste the code above into the Module.
4. With the cursor inside the code press F5 to run the `StyleCleanup` macro.
5. Give it 10-20 minutes to do its work!